# How to update redux state one by one and return last state?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I want check string contain uppercase and lowercase etc .i have initial state of all false and I want to update the states depends on value enter. I want to return the state at the end of case with updated states.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {lowercaseStatus:false,upperCaseEditStatus:false,allStatus:false}
    export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {  
     switch (action.type)
     { 
    case INPUT:

    If(uppercase(action.payload.value))  
    {

    Update       upperCaseEditStatus to true 
    }       

    If(lowerCase(action.payload.value))  
    {

    Update       lowercaseStatus to true 
    }  

    If(other condition)
    {
    Upates props depends on corresponding condition
    }    


    retrun state; 
    }
```

Let me know how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `...` ,spread operator, for immutability of state object like this,

```
case INPUT:
  temp = {};
  temp.upperCaseEditStatus = uppercase(action.payload.value)
  temp.lowercaseStatus = lowerCase(action.payload.value)
  ... //Other conditions
  return { ...state, ...temp };
default:
  return state;
```